# React equivalent to ng-model

Tags: reactjs

New to React, I have a TextField that I want to "bind" a value to it, I want it to change the value if the user enters value into the TextField and update the TextField if the value change through some API call.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: have you learned about `state` in React?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using `state` and `onChange`. Simple example included below:

```
<TextField
  onChange={(name) => this.setState({name})}
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```

A guide for updating `TextInput` based on a variable is [located in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html).

Comment: I have to use this: `<input value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}></input>`. How is yours working? What am I doing different?

Comment: @Frank A `TextField` and an `input` are not the same. They just expect different parameters.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this in React is with `state`. Here's an example in JSX:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'default',
      text2: 'default'
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    var obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState(obj);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input type="text" name="text2" value={this.state.text2} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing with **React hook**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default MyForm = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('default')
  const [text2, setText2] = useState('default')

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="text" value={text} onChange={(e)=> setText(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" name="text2" value={text2} onChange={(e)=> setText2(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways data binding in angular work out of the box by using [ngModal](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description) directive

> **NgModal**: Creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a form control element

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>

    <p>Value: {{ name }}</p>
    <p>Valid: {{ ctrl.valid }}</p>

    <button (click)="setValue()">Set value</button>
  `,
})
export class SimpleNgModelComp {
  name: string = '';

  setValue() { this.name = 'Nancy'; }
}
```

In ReactJS, we don't have such a built-in option to handle two ways data binding, you need to use the state and add an onChange event to the input.
React Controlled Input allow us to implement data binding in React: we bind a value to a state variable and an onChange event to change the state as the input value changes.

Refer to the below snippet:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {name : ''}
  }
  handleChange = (e) =>{ 
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
    </div>
   )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward using [useState](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState) React Hook and [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("hello");

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={setText} />
      <Text>Text value: {text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-haze-9b19lm?file=/src/App.js)